# SpringFox Date format to milliseconds

Tags: documentation, swagger, swagger-2.0, springfox

I'm using [SpringFox (Swagger)](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/) to document my REST APIs. One of the nice features in Swagger is to show example model and the data type format.

Now, I configured my APIs to produce and consume dates in milliseconds but when I'm looking at the sample JSON model the date format is following: `"2015-09-21T00:51:32.617Z"`. See screenshot below. Is it possible to tell SpringFox (Swagger) how to format the date properly?

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to format my date "YYYY-MM-DD".
Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Nope, I didn't find a solution for that. I just had to tell the developer to assume that all dates will be in the format that I specified and don't look at the Swagged date format. Check out this GitHub issue that I raised with the springfox devs: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/979

Answer (score 5):

You could try:

```
   Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .apiInfo(getApiInfo())
                    .directModelSubstitute(YourDateTimeClass.class, Integer.class);
```

Basically you are telling Swagger to replace the date class with an Integer which could represent the milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

This is related to the underlying Jackson serialiser. You have to set the correct date format for it otherwise by default it's using timestamps.

Here is an example configuration

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
            if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter;
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = jsonMessageConverter.getObjectMapper();
                objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way it will use an ISO-8601 date-time format. Here is another blog post that explains how to set your own preferred date format: http://yysource.com/2016/06/change-default-date-for-jackson-in-spring-boot-application/

Comment: +1 I'm using spring-hateoas, which is quite nice, but doesn't bind ObjectMapper as a bean. I've been looking for how to access the ObjectMapper for the last few days! Thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem as yours, and I resolved it by adding the following config in my Spring Boot's `application.properties` file:

`spring.jackson.date-format=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat`